# Creating guard in Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a guard, authentication part was working but when I created *auth-guard.guard.ts* then I got several errors:

> Error: src/app/app.module.ts:52:7 - error TS2322: Type '{
> AuthService: typeof AuthService; provide:
> InjectionToken<HttpInterceptor[]>; useClass: typeof AuthInterceptor;
> multi: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'AuthService' does not exist in type 'Provider'.
>
> ```
> 52       AuthService,
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>
> Error: src/app/auth/guard/auth-guard.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../shared/token.service"' has no exported member
> ```
>
> 'AuthService'.
>
> ```
> 4 import { AuthService } from '../../shared/token.service';
>            ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>
> Error: src/app/auth/guard/auth-guard.ts:10:23 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter '_authService' of class
> ```
>
> 'AuthGuard'.
> Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.
>
> ```
> 10   constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }
>                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   src/app/auth/guard/auth-guard.ts:10:37
>     10   constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }
>                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
>     This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as injection token.
> ```
>
> auth/guard/auth-guard.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree,Router  } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { AuthService } from '../../shared/token.service';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthGuardGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }
      canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this._router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false
        }
    }
      
    }
```

> shared/token.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TokenService {

  private issuer = {
    login: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login',
    register: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register'
  }

  constructor() { }

  handleData(token  : any){
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', token);
  }

  getToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  // Verify the token
  isValidToken(){
     const token = this.getToken();

     if(token){
       const payload = this.payload(token);
       if(payload){
         return Object.values(this.issuer).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
       }
     } else {
        return false;
     }
  }

  payload(token  : any) {
    const jwtPayload = token.split('.')[1];
    return JSON.parse(atob(jwtPayload));
  }

  // User state based on valid token
  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.isValidToken();
  }

  // Remove token
  removeToken(){
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
  }

}
```

> shared/auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// User interface
export class User {
  name: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;
  password_confirmation: String
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // User registration
  register(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register', user);
  }

  // Login
  signin(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', user);
  }

  // Access user profile
  profileUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/user-profile');
  }

}
```

> app.modules.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RagisterComponent } from './ragister/ragister.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/auth.interceptor';
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CarouselModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      AuthService,
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { RagisterComponent } from './ragister/ragister.component';
import { UserdashboardComponent } from './userdashboard/userdashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/guard/auth-guard.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'ragister',component:RagisterComponent},
  {path:'dashboard',component:UserdashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Any Solution, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guard is called `AuthGuardGuard` instead of `AuthGuard`. You probably created it with

`ng generate guard AuthGuard`

instead of

`ng generate guard Auth`

You can just rename the file and class or delete/recreate (preferred solution)

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have updated my guard class to AuthGuard but still getting 3 errors Can you please check the error i have updated in my question

Comment: I have `isLoggedIn()` method in token.service method which checks whether token is valid or not, Can you please let me know which file to include, `auth.service` has no such method

Comment: @user3653474 Forget it. After reading the question again, I understand that you actually really have 2 different services, `AuthService` and `TokenService`. But, except if you have both in the same file, this import is wrong: `import { AuthService } from '../../shared/token.service';`

Comment: yes they are both seperate service, is there any solution for that because then i will have to modify the services

Comment: Can you try to fix the import and tell me if you have other error messages ? Try this : `import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service'; import { TokenService } from '../../shared/token.service';`

Comment: I tried `import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';` in the guard file within canActivate method i'm getting `Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'` i think this is because this method does not exist in auth service, and second error is in app.module.ts  `Type '{ AuthService: typeof AuthService; provide: InjectionToken<HttpInterceptor[]>; useClass: typeof AuthInterceptor; multi: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'AuthService' does not exist in type 'Provider'`

Comment: @user3653474 If `isLoggedIn` is in the TokenService, it means that you have to inject the TokenService also. The constructor becomes `constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _tokenService: TokenService, private _router: Router) { }` then you can call `this._tokenService.isLoggedIn()`

Comment: i have included these two service `import { TokenService } from '../../shared/token.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service'` auth-guard.ts, updated constructor to `constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router,_tokenService: TokenService) { }` but in if condition still getting one error `Property '_tokenService' does not exist on type 'AuthGuard'.`

Comment: You forgot the `private` on `tokenService` in the constructor

Comment: Thanks it resolved the issue i want to know one thing more is it necessary to include `import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';`  or `import { TokenService } from '../../shared/token.service'` service in app.module.ts to add it in provider array

Comment: Short answer is Nope, because they are `providedIn: 'root'`. More info on dependency injection [here](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection). This is important to understand because dependency injection is a concept that you will use in every decent language/framework

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the Auth Guard Class name.

You should either change the auth guard class name from `AuthGuardGuard` to `AuthGuard`

OR

Change it in `routing.module.ts` from

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/guard/auth-guard.guard';
{path:'dashboard',component:UserdashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

TO

```
import { AuthGuardGuard } from './auth/guard/auth-guard.guard';
{path:'dashboard',component:UserdashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuardGuard]}
```